# How to take the logarithm to get the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\left ( 1+\frac{1}{2^{2^{k} } } \right )} $

Tags: limits

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\left ( 1+\frac{1}{2^{2^{k} } }  \right )}  
 $

Let $ a_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\left ( 1+\frac{1}{2^{2^{k} } }  \right )} $ ,
$
\left( 1-\frac{1}{2^2} \right) a_n=\left( 1-\frac{1}{2^2} \right) \left( 1+\frac{1}{2^2} \right) \cdots \left( 1+\frac{1}{2^{2n}} \right) =
1-\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}$
$a_n=\frac{4}{3}\left( 1-\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}} \right) ,n\longrightarrow \infty ,a_n\longrightarrow \frac{4}{3}$
I want to solve it by taking the logarithm
$\lim _{n \to \infty } \exp \left [ \ln{\left ( 1+\frac{1}{{4}^{k} }  \right ) }-\ln 1  \right ], $
$\left[ \ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{4^k} \right) -\ln 1 \right] =\frac{1}{1+\theta \frac{1}{4^k}}\frac{1}{4^k}\text{，}\theta \epsilon \left( 0,1 \right) $
$1<1+\theta \frac{1}{4^k}<1+\frac{1}{4^k},\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{4^k}}}\times \frac{1}{4^k}<\sum_{k=1}^n{\left[ \ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{4^k} \right) -\ln 1 \right]}<\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{4^k}}$
but how  to do next?

Comment: "$ a_n={\left ( 1+\frac{1}{2^{2^{k} } }  \right )} $"?? What is the relation between $n$ and $k$ here?

Comment: I have corrected the mistake, the correct form is$ a_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\left ( 1+\frac{1}{2^{2^{k} } }  \right )} $

Answer (score 2):

One basic way to solve this is to see what the partial products are...
$$a_1=\Bigg(1+\frac{1}{2^2}\Bigg)$$
$$a_2=\Bigg(1+\frac{1}{2^2}\Bigg)\Bigg(1+\frac{1}{2^4}\Bigg)=1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^6}$$
$$a_3=\Bigg(1+\frac{1}{2^2}\Bigg)\Bigg(1+\frac{1}{2^4}\Bigg)\Bigg(1+\frac{1}{2^8}\Bigg)=1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^6}+\frac{1}{2^8}+\frac{1}{2^{10}}+\frac{1}{2^{12}}+\frac{1}{2^{14}}$$

proceeding we get $$a_n=1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^6}+\frac{1}{2^8}+\frac{1}{2^{10}}+\frac{1}{2^{12}}+\frac{1}{2^{14}}+...+\frac{1}{2^{2(2^n-1)}}$$

Which is essentially a geometric series with common ratio $\frac{1}{2^2}$

and hence the limit is $$\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^2}}=\frac{4}{3}$$